# How to permanently connect to WPA2AES wifi with OpenBSD (through cli)

Tags: wifi, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD 5.1 i386 installed. I have no GUI/X. I googled for the answer but I can't find authentic one. How can I connect to a WPA2 PSK/AES wifi network using only the terminal? (so I don't have a "network manager" to simply select the given SSID, then enter passphare :D)

**UPDATE:**
wifi card: Atheros AR5424, I can see it as "ath0"

**UPDATE#2:**

```
DHCP NWID SSID wpakey SSIDPWD
```

doesn't worked in /etc/hostname.ath0 (then the sh /etc/netstart ath0)

**UPDATE#3:**

```
ifconfig ath0 nwid SSID wpa wpapsk $(wpa-psk SSID SSIDPWD)
```

gived:

```
ksh: wpa-psk not found
ifconfig: wpapsk: bad value
```

**UPDATE#4:**

The router is an OpenWrt 10.03.1 box:

```
cat /etc/config/wireless
config 'wifi-iface'
    option 'device' 'radio0'
    option 'network' 'lan'
    option 'mode' 'ap'
    option 'ssid' 'SSID'
    option 'encryption' 'psk2+ccmp'
    option 'key' 'SSIDPWD'
    option 'isolate' '1'
    option 'maxassoc' '1'
```

I didn't seen anything in the logs associated to the openbsd eee pc 701 :D

**UPDATE#5:**
I tested the SSID with the SSIDPWD, and it worked on a Scientific Linux 6.3 notebook.

**UPDATE#6:**

```
ifconfig ath0 nwid SSID wpakey SSIDPWD
```

I tried this one too, it didn't gived back any error messages, but I still can't see anything on the openwrt router, that it tries to connect, I can only see change in "ifconfig ath0" - I can see the "ieee8011" line is filled up.

**UPDATE#7:**
whoops :) I maybe have an idea what is the problem. :D I only have the motherboard of the eee pc 701 and the wifi card in it.. :D with NO ANTENNAS :D - so I will try to find an antenna :)

Comment: anyone? :) I have to put a bounty on this :)

Comment: wpa_supplicant doens't work for you?

Comment: but how?? :) what are the exact commands? :O

Comment: What wireless network adapter are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a hostname file in /etc with the interface's name.

```
/etc/hostname.iwn0
```

Add to it:

```
dhcp nwid "Name of network" wpakey password
```

Restart the interface.

```
sudo sh /etc/netstart iwn0
```

This way connection to the wireless network will be attempted on boot.

---

If you don't know the name of the wireless interface run,

```
ifconfig
```

and look for 802.11 in 'media' or wlan in 'groups'.

Comment: @gaskopeter, I am using the exact same way of configuration for my wireless card. kuda has outlined the correct procedure and you can find it in OpenBSD faqs too. I think either you did not name your hostname file correctly - hostname.{interface name} or you did not specify wpakey password correctly in that file.

Answer (score 4):

From what I have been reading, apparently on OpenBSD you can configure the SSID and WPA shared secret key on the `ifconfig` command line.

Please see:

http://vinci.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/using-wpa-on-openbsd/

> Configure ral0 to join network “my_net” using WPA-PSK with passphrase
>   “my_passphrase”:

```
    # ifconfig ral0 nwid my_net wpa wpapsk \
         $(wpa-psk my_net my_passphrase)
```

and

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ral&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html

> Configure ral0 to join network `my_net'' using WPA with passphrase`
>   my_passphrase'':

```
    # ifconfig ral0 nwid my_net wpakey my_passphrase
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `ifconfig ath0 nwid SSID wpakey SSIDPWD` didn't work.  After you run this command, if you just enter `ifconfig` what is displayed?  Do you get an IP address or any 802.11 information?  Can you safely post what is displayed for that command here?

Comment: "ifconfig ath0" displayed 802.11 information, but it didn't displayed IP address :)

Comment: Here's an example from Wikipedia that shows an interface that has associated with the access point `ieee80211: nwid ARK chan 11 bssid 00:0d:0b:ed:84:fb  100dBm`, does yours show that?  It would be very helpful if you could post what ifconfig returns for you.